# Why an unhandled exception on timer thread doesn't crash the process

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, asynchronous, unhandled-exception

I am aware of how unhanded exceptions are processed when using `Task`s, only throwing an unhandled in the finalizer if user code hasn't 'observed' it yet.

I am also aware of how an unhandled exception in an async thread (e.g. `Action.BeginInvoke()`) is caught and re-thrown on the joining call (e.g. `Action.EndInvoke()`).

What I don't understand though is how this doesn't crash the process?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer() {Interval = 100};
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => { throw new Exception(); };
        timer.Start();

        Console.ReadKey( true );
    }
```

Comment: Well this was 4-6 hours of my life i'll never get back. What a horrible decision on Microsoft's part for this to not crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the .NET 4.0 documentation:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0 and earlier, the Timer component
>   catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the
>   Elapsed event. This behavior is subject to change in future releases
>   of the .NET Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

There is no statement yet claiming that this behavior has actually changed.

Comment: Ahh that would be it, Thanks - I did actually read that page, but must of missed it. I think I foolishly assumed that something that goes against all of their standard practice of not suppressing unhandled exceptions would have been inside one of those nice yellow boxes.

Comment: @Tyson, agreed. It introduces an ugly inconsistence with other places.